# How could I merge documents from two different collections

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

How could I merge documents from two different collections.

From  `shopping_collection` we can get purchase history,

To get the details of each purchase history I need to get the information from `detailed_shopping_list_collection`

But it seems not possible to do this with `aggregate` because of collections are different ?

How could I get it with **mapreduce** ?

## shopping_collection

```
{
  "name": "Mary",
  "gender": "M",
  "birthday": new Date("1980-04-01T08:00:00+0800"),
  "records": [
    {
      "BUY_DATE": new Date("1996-02-08T08:00:00+0800"),
      "SEQ_NO": 768,
    },
    {
      "BUY_DATE": new Date("1996-02-06T08:00:00+0800"),
      "SEQ_NO": 595,
    }
}
```

## detailed_shopping_list_collection

```
{
  "BUY_DATE": new Date("1996-02-08T08:00:00+0800"),
  "SEQ_NO": 768
  "ITEM_NAME": "iphone4s"
  "PRICE": 500
},
{
  "BUY_DATE": new Date("1996-02-08T08:00:00+0800"),
  "SEQ_NO": 768
  "ITEM_NAME": "iphone4s"
  "PRICE": 500
},
{
  "BUY_DATE": new Date("1996-02-08T08:00:00+0800"),
  "SEQ_NO": 768
  "ITEM_NAME": "macbook"
  "PRICE": 700
}
```

## Expected aggregated result

```
{
  "name": "Mary",
  "gender": "M",
  "birthday": new Date("1980-04-01T08:00:00+0800"),
  "records": [
    {
      "BUY_DATE": new Date("1996-02-08T08:00:00+0800"),
      "SEQ_NO": 768,
      "PURCHASE_HISTORY":[
        {"ITEM_NAME": "iphone4s"
                "PRICE": 500},
        {"ITEM_NAME": "iphone4s"
                "PRICE": 500},                
        {"ITEM_NAME": "macbook"
                    "PRICE": 700}
      ]
      "UNIQUE_PURCHASE_ITEMS":[ "iphone4s", "macbook"
      ]
    },
    {
      "BUY_DATE": new Date("1996-02-06T08:00:00+0800"),
      "SEQ_NO": 595,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve should be done on client side using multiple queries, since mapreduce is not to be replacement for joins. However, there are some interesting approaches suggested by some people, e.g. http://tebros.com/2011/07/using-mongodb-mapreduce-to-join-2-collections/.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below query :

```
// MAP FUNCTION LOGIC 

var map = function(){
 var arr = new Array();
 this.records.forEach(function(doc){ 
   var temp = db.detailed_shopping_list_collection.find(
       {"BUY_DATE": doc.BUY_DATE, "SEQ_NO" : doc.SEQ_NO}); 
   arr.push(temp); 
                 });
 emit(this._id,{"name" : this.name, "gender" :
  this.gender, "birthday" :   this.birthday, "records" : arr );
}


// REDUCE FUNCTION LOGIC

var reduce = function(id , doc){ return doc; }


// MAP REDUCE CALL
db.shopping_collection.mapReduce( map,reduce,{out: {inline :1}} );
```